# Null value of a String field on a projection object

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

In a Spring Boot application I have a class with compound id defined as follows:

```
@Embeddable
public class StatisticId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String shortName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 32, nullable = false)
    private Month month;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int year;

    // getters, setters, equals, hashCode, toString
}
```

The (simplified) class definition is:

```
@Entity
public class Statistic implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private BigDecimal sales;

    @EmbeddedId
    private StatisticId id;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

I want to make a projection of this class:

```
public interface StatisticProjection {
    public String getShortName();
    public Month getMonth();
    public int getYear();
    public BigDecimal getSales();
}
```

and use it in the following repository:

```
public interface StatisticsRepository extends CrudRepository<Statistic, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select short_name, month, year, sales from statistic where short_name in = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Iterable<StatisticProjection> findByShortName(Collection<String> shortNames);

}
```

The result of the *findByShortName* method invocation results in a list of elements that I expected, except that each of them has null-valued *shortName* (the other fields are correct).

I execute exactly the same query directly on MySQL data base and it returns proper values of a **short_name** column.

What should I do to have a valid *shortName* on my projection class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Projections don't seem to work very well with native queries, underscored ones to be more precise. To get a field which has an underscore in it use an underscore in the get method. So instead of using `getShortName()` use `getShort_name()`

Comment: Helped me a lot, however I found that changed in my case when I migrated from Spring boot 1.5.9 to 2.4.4. I don't know in which release it happened but in older Spring version I could use `getShortName` when I retrieved `short_name` from DB with native query. But in new Spring I needed to use your suggestion.